# Как в django вывести в админку настройку какой либо текстовой информации в шаблоне

Tags: django

Как в *Django* вывести в админку настройку какой либо текстовой информации в шаблоне?

Например: у меня есть пара страниц *главная* и *о нас*. На странице должны присутствовать по несколько блоков с текстовой информацией, которую можно редактировать через админку.

Количество блоков фиксировано и различно для каждой страницы.

Создание моделей тут не подходит.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой и очевидный путь  - держать шаблон в базе данных.
Создайте модель, в самом простом случае - содержащее текстовое поле и название шаблона.

```
from django.template import Template
from myapp.models import DbTmpl

a = DbTmpl.objects.get(name='contacts').html
tmpl = Template(a)
tmpl.render({'phone' : '111-22-33', 'city' : 'Moscow'})
```

Дальше все зависит от задач и фантазии.
Кроме этого, для таких случаев есть батарейка: http://django-dbtemplates.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

вот практически то что нужно было:

куски текста редактируемые через админку:

https://github.com/funkybob/django-flatblocks